# render fieldsets as vertical tabs - not as form - but as output

Tags: theming

I created an entity. The content is shown in fieldsets like this:

```
$build['pricing'] = array(
  '#type' => 'vertical_tabs',       
);

$build['pricedef_kauf'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Price'),
  '#group'=> 'pricing',
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  '#attributes'=> array('class' => array('vertical-tabs-pane')),
);
```

But it is not recognized as vertical tab as I hoped. Only the class vertical-tabs-pane is added. The js is not called!?